# $(window).resize conditional = if page is less than

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize, appendto

I want to move an element (div) in the dom from one place to another using jQuery. I have the code working almost too well, in that it's appending my code every single time the browser is resized and then carries on until the browser crashes.

Here's my code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
    if(bodyWidth < 740){
        $('.GalleryHeader').appendTo('li');
    }
});
```

How do I get this to only run once, so it only does the one time, and then perhaps put it back into it's original location in the dom when resizing back up over 740px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    var flag;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var bodyWidth = $(window).width();
        console.log(bodyWidth)
        if (flag !== false && bodyWidth < 740) {
            //move the element to new location
            console.log('less')
            flag = false;
        } else if (flag !== true && bodyWidth >= 740) {
            //put it back to original location
            console.log('more')
            flag = true;
        }
    }).resize();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MdX8r/)

Comment: Thanks @arun-p-johny! This looks like the right thing, and works when I resize down but when I resize UP it adds many instances of the .GalleryHeader. What could be causing this do you think?

Comment: @tjcss can you edit the fiddle to recreate the problem... because from what I can see the conditions are satisfied only once...

Comment: Strange, your example works fine on jsfiddle with my HTML, but not on my site locally, must be something else interfering with it.